# How to make layouts and view's for RLT screen (for hebrew)

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want create UI for Android app which support's `RLT` (Right to Left direction).

I like `ConstraintLayout` too, so I have little headache.

This is little piece of my UI (mockup):

[image]

Can I make adaptive UI using `ConstraintLayouts`? (I tried find something for me, but I didn't find solution)

Comment: yes definitely. there was a bug in the early versions but its fixed now ... check the link https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222556

Comment: @MohanadALKHOULI yes, but if I try to change something in UI I get big error in UI - and it bad (

Comment: Isn't using end/start enough ? If so post layout code so we can try figure it out.